# Which close() runs first?

Tags: java, jdbc

If I have multiple resources, in a try catch, which one gets closed called on first?

```
public class TestRes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestRes tr = new TestRes();
    tr.test();
  }

  public void test() {
    try (MyResource1 r1 = new MyResource1(); MyResource2 r2 = new MyResource2(); ) {
       System.out.print("T ");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.print("IOE ");
    } finally {
      System.out.print("F ");
    }
  }

  class MyResource1 implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
      System.out.print("1 ");
    }
  }

  class MyResource2 implements Closeable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
      throw new IOException();
    }
  }
}
```

This sample outputs:

```
T 1 IOE F
```

If I change the order so...

```
public class TestRes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestRes tr = new TestRes();
    tr.test();
  }

  public void test() {
    try (MyResource2 r2 = new MyResource2(); MyResource1 r1 = new MyResource1();) {
       System.out.print("T ");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.print("IOE ");
    } finally {
      System.out.print("F ");
    }
  }

  class MyResource1 implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
      System.out.print("1 ");
    }
  }

  class MyResource2 implements Closeable {
    public void close() throws IOException {
      throw new IOException();
    }
  }
}
```

I get the same output - why?

Comment: **Why** did you expect something different? Explain! --- Only one of the `close()` methods print anything, so how did you expect the code to show you the order in which `close()` is invoked? --- Or did you mistakenly think that exception from one of the `close()` methods would prevent the other from being called? Try-with-resources explicitly states that *all* `close()` methods will be called. It's why they added *suppressed* exception support in the same version they added try-with-resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you believe an exception from a `close()` method will prevent other `close()` methods from being called. That is *wrong*.

The Java Language Specification, section [14.20.3. try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), says:

> Resources are **closed in the reverse order** from that in which they were initialized. A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value. **An exception from the closing of one resource *does not* prevent the closing of other resources**. Such an exception is *suppressed* if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource.

Which means that the `close()` method printing `1` will always be executed, and the first part answers your *"Which `close()` runs first?"* question.